# How to check that AsyncLocal<T> is accessed within same "async context"

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

**TL;DR** `ThreadLocal<T>.Value` points to same location if `Thread.CurrentThread` stays the same. Is there anything similar  for `AsyncLocal<T>.Value` (e.g. would `SychronizationContext.Current` or `ExecutionContext.Capture()` suffice for all scenarios)?

---

Imagine we have created some snapshot of data structure which is kept in thread-local storage (e.g. `ThreadLocal<T>` instance) and passed it to axillary class for later use. This axillary class is used to restore this data structure to snapshot state. We don't want to restore this snapshot onto different thread, so we can check on which thread axillary class was created. For example:

```
class Storage<T>
{
    private ThreadLocal<ImmutableStack<T>> stackHolder;

    public IDisposable Push(T item)
    {
        var bookmark = new StorageBookmark<T>(this);
        stackHolder.Value = stackHolder.Value.Push(item);
        return bookmark;
    }

    private class StorageBookmark<TInner> :IDisposable
    {
        private Storage<TInner> owner;
        private ImmutableStack<TInner> snapshot;
        private Thread boundThread;

        public StorageBookmark(Storage<TInner> owner)
        { 
             this.owner = owner;
             this.snapshot = owner.stackHolder.Value;
             this.boundThread  = Thread.CurrentThread;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
             if(Thread.CurrentThread != boundThread) 
                 throw new InvalidOperationException ("Bookmark crossed thread boundary");
             owner.stackHolder.Value = snapshot;
        }
    }
}
```

With this, we essentialy bound StorageBookmark to specific thread, and, therefore, to specific version of data structure in ThreadLocal storage. And we did that by assuring we don't cross "thread context" with the help of `Thread.CurrentThread` 
Now, to question at hand. How can we achieve the same behavior with `AsyncLocal<T>` instead of `ThreadLocal<T>`? To be precise, is there anything similar to `Thread.CurrentThread` which can be checked at times of construction and usage to control that "async context" has not been crossed (That means `AsyncLocal<T>.Value` would point to same object as when bookmark was constructed).
It seems either `SynchronizationContext.Current` or `ExecutionContext.Capture()` may suffice, but I'm not sure which is better and that there is no catch (or even that would work in all possible situations)

Comment: I would think you could craft your async calls to remain on a context with ConfigureAwait(true)

Comment: @Crowcoder `ConfigureAwait(true)` is redundant.  The context is always captured if you omit the call entirely.

Comment: @Servy I know, I just meant I don't see the problem yet.

Comment: @Crowcoder If you don't see the problem then why suggesting doing something that doesn't do anything?  The problem is of course that a caller might *not* use this object from a single synchronization context, when they're supposed to, and that they wouldn't realize that this code doesn't support that.  It's not that it's not possible to perform continautions using a synchronization context, or that the OP doesn't know how to.

Comment: @Servy I'm suggesting that OP make sure the method calls do not cause a context switch. I don't see why the use of `AsyncLocal<T>` would be any different than any context aware code. But since it is important to remain on context, `ConfigureAwait(true)` is not a bad idea to convey the intent to the maintainers of the code.

Comment: Well, you can't use `ConfigureAwait` when there is no `Task` to be awaited, therefore you have to use `ConfigureAwait` in every case this code is used within async operation... and it still won't prevent using this code from different context (and fail late). The problem at hand is to fail early.

Comment: Yes, copying SynchronizationContext.Current should get the job done.  Pretty hard to get a warranty, the underlying framework code has been changing a lot and is getting awfully convoluted.

Comment: Actually, in case anyone is confused by these comments, ExecutionContext (where AsyncLocal is stored) is independent from SynchronizationContext. You can not (rather, should not, and particularly can not via ConfigureAwait) prevent the flow of ExecutionContext; it would be rather problematic without taking very particular care. ConfigureAwait only controls whether or not SynchronizationContext is captured (which would be to ensure execution resumes on your various UI threads, HTTP Request contexts, etc. and is much less fundamental to logical context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical call context has the same flow semantics as the execution context, and therefore as `AsyncLocal`. Knowing that, you can store a value in the logical context to detect when you cross "async context" boundaries:

```
class Storage<T>
{
    private AsyncLocal<ImmutableStack<T>> stackHolder = new AsyncLocal<ImmutableStack<T>>();

    public IDisposable Push(T item)
    {
        var bookmark = new StorageBookmark<T>(this);

        stackHolder.Value = (stackHolder.Value ?? ImmutableStack<T>.Empty).Push(item);
        return bookmark;
    }

    private class StorageBookmark<TInner> : IDisposable
    {
        private Storage<TInner> owner;
        private ImmutableStack<TInner> snapshot;
        private Thread boundThread;
        private readonly object id;

        public StorageBookmark(Storage<TInner> owner)
        {
            id = new object();
            this.owner = owner;
            this.snapshot = owner.stackHolder.Value;
            CallContext.LogicalSetData("AsyncStorage", id);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (CallContext.LogicalGetData("AsyncStorage") != id)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Bookmark crossed async context boundary");
            owner.stackHolder.Value = snapshot;
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DoesNotThrow().Wait();
        Throws().Wait();
    }

    static async Task DoesNotThrow()
    {
        var storage = new Storage<string>();

        using (storage.Push("hello"))
        {
            await Task.Yield();
        }
    }

    static async Task Throws()
    {
        var storage = new Storage<string>();

        var disposable = storage.Push("hello");

        using (ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow())
        {
            Task.Run(() => { disposable.Dispose(); }).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea of tracking changes via separate local value is good (another instance of AsyncLocal would suffice as well), however it is still has trouble with copy-on-write behavior of context. If you remove `ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow()` in second example, bookmark won't throw exception, but not because async context is the same, but because new child context copied the state from its parent. After you push something into this child context - then it will became different from parent, and bookmark will throw on disposal

Comment: @Aloraman I'm not sure I understand to be honest. Let's say I call `await Task.Yield()`. Do you consider that we're on the same context before and after or on a different one? Because the actual ExecutionContext object will be different. If you consider it to be different (and therefore want to throw), then you can check if the reference `Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContext` has changed.

Comment: Ha, I see... So in sequence `(before)` -> `await Task.Yield()` -> `(after)` the execution context in `after` is not the same as in `before`, but a shallow copy (as well as in forking scenario). I was  assuming it was the same 'context in a sense' (when you modify `AsyncLocal` state in `after`, its previous state in `before` is no longer accessible), so I hoped I could ensure linear flow of data. So if continuation on this 'context in a sense' internally is no different than continuation via Task.Run (which allows forking of ExecutionContext), then simple 'fail fast' detection is not possible

Comment: The CallContext will also travel across AppDomain boundaries whereas AsyncLocal will not, so there are situations within the same logical context that will not remain consistent under some conditions.

Answer (score 3):

What you're hoping to do is fundamentally contrary to the nature of asynchronous execution context; you're not required to (and therefore can't guarantee) that all Tasks created within your asynchronous context will be awaited immediately, in the same order they were created, or ever at all, but their creation within the scope of the calling context makes them part of the same asynchronous context, period.

It may be challenging to think of asynchronous execution context as different from thread contexts, but asynchrony is not synonymous with parallelism, which is specifically what logical threads support. Objects stored in Thread Local Storage that aren't intended to be shared/copied across threads can generally be mutable because execution within a logical thread will always be able to guarantee relatively constrained sequential logic (if some special treatment may be necessary to ensure compile-time optimizations don't mess with you, though this is rare and only necessary in very specific scenarios). For that reason the `ThreadLocal` in your example doesn't really need to be an `ImmutableStack`, it could just be a `Stack` (which has much better performance) since you don't need to worry about copy-on-write or concurrent access. If the stack were publicly accessible then it would be more concerning that someone could pass the stack to other threads which could push/pop items, but since it's a private implementation detail here the `ImmutableStack` could actually be seen as unnecessary complexity.

Anyway, Execution Context, which is not a unique concept to .NET (implementations on other platforms may differ in some ways, though in my experience never by much) is very much like (and directly related to) the call stack, but in a way that considers new asynchronous tasks to be new calls on the stack which may need to both share the caller's state as it was at the time the operation was executed, as well as diverge since the caller may continue to create more tasks and create/update state in ways that will not make logical sense when reading a sequential set of instructions. It is generally recommended that anything placed in the `ExecutionContext` be immutable, though in some cases all copies of the context still pointing to the same instance reference should necessarily share mutable data. `IHttpContext`, for instance, is stored on the default implementation of `IHttpContextAccessor` using `AsyncLocal`, so all tasks created in the scope of a single request will have access to the same response state, for example. Allowing multiple concurrent contexts to make mutations to the same reference instance necessarily introduces the possibility of issues, both from concurrency and logical order of execution. For instance, multiple tasks trying to set different results on an HTTP response will either result in an exception or unexpected behavior. You can try, to some extent, to help the consumer here, but at the end of the day it is the consumer's responsibility to understand the complexity of the nuanced implementation details they're dependent on (which is generally a code smell, but sometimes a necessary evil in real world situations).

That scenario aside, as said, for the sake of ensuring all nested contexts function predictably and safely it's generally recommended to only store immutable types and to always restore the context to its previous value (as you're doing with you disposable stack mechanism). The easiest way to think of the copy-on-write behavior is as though every single new task, new thread pool work item, and new thread gets its own clone of the context, but if they point to the same reference type (i.e. all have copies of the same *reference pointer*) they all have the same instance; the copy-on-write is simply an optimization that prevents copying when unnecessary, but can essentially be completely ignored and thought of as every logical task having its own copy *of the context* (which is very much like that `ImmutableStack` or a string). If the only way to update anything about the current value *that the immutable collection item points to* is to reassign it to a new modified instance then you never have to worry about cross-context pollution (just like that `ImmutableStack` you're using).

Your example doesn't show anything about how the data is accessed or what types are passed in for `T` so there's no way to see what issue you might face, but if what you're concerned about is nested tasks disposing the "Current" context or the IDisposable value being assigned to a field somewhere and accessed from a different thread, there's a few things you can try and some points worth considering:

- The closest equivalent to your current check would be:

```cs
if(stackHolder.Value != this) 
    throw new InvalidOperationException ("Bookmark disposed out of order or in wrong context");
```

- A simple `ObjectDisposedException` will throw an exception from at least one context if two contexts try to dispose it.
- Though this generally isn't recommended, if you want to be absolutely certain the object was disposed at least once you could throw an exception in the finalizer of the `IDisposable` implementation (being sure to call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` in the Dispose method).
- By combining the previous two, while it won't guarantee that it was disposed in the exact some task/method block that created it, you can at least guarantee that an object is disposed once and only once.
- Due to the fundamental importance of the ways `ExecutionContext` is supposed to be flowed and controlled, it is the responsibility of the execution engine (typically the runtime, task scheduler, etc. but also in cases where a third party is using Tasks/Threads in novel ways) to ensure `ExecutionContext` flow is captured and suppressed where appropriate. If a thread, scheduler, or synchronization migration occurs in the root context, the `ExecutionContext` should not be flowed into the next logical task's `ExecutionContext` the thread/scheduler processes in the context where the task formerly executed. For example, if a task continuation starts on a `ThreadPool` thread and then awaits continuation that causes the next logical operations to continue on a different `ThreadPool` Thread than it was originally started on or some other I/O resource completion thread, when the original thread is returned the the `ThreadPool` it should not continue to reference/flow the `ExecutionContext` of the task which is no longer logically executing within it. Assuming no additional tasks are created in parallel and left astray, once execution resumes in the root awaiter it will be the only execution context that continues to have a reference to the context. When a Task completes, so does its execution context (or, rather, its copy of it).
- Even if unobserved background tasks are started and never awaited, if the data stored in the `AsyncLocal` is immutable, the copy-on-write behavior combined with your immutable stack will ensure that parallel clones of execution contexts can never pollute each other
- With the first check and used with immutable types, you really don't need to worry about cloned parallel execution contexts unless you're worried about them gaining access to sensitive data from previous contexts; when they Dispose the current item only the stack of the current execution context (e.g. the nested parallel context, specifically) reverts to the previous; all cloned contexts (including the parent) are not modified.
- If you *are* worried about nested contexts accessing parent data by disposing things they shouldn't there are relatively simple patterns you can use to separate the `IDisposable` from the ambient value, as well as suppression patterns like those used in `TransactionScope` to, say, temporarily set the current value to `null`, etc.

Just to reiterate in a practical way, let's say, for instance, that you store an `ImmutableList` in one of your bookmarks. If the item stored in the `ImmutableList` is mutable then context pollution is possible.

```cs
var someImmutableListOfMutableItems = unsafeAsyncLocal.Value;
// sets Name for all contexts pointing to the reference type.
someImmutableListOfMutableItems[0].Name = "Jon"; // assigns property setter on shared reference of Person
// notice how unsafeAsyncLocal.Value never had to be reassigned?
```

Whereas an immutable collection of immutable items will never pollute another context unless something is super fundamentally wrong about how execution context is being flowed (contact a vendor, file a bug report, raise the alarm, etc.)

```cs
var someImmutableListOfImmutableItems = safeAsyncLocal.Value;

someImmutableListOfImmutableItems = someImmutableListOfImmutableItems.SetItem(0, 
    someImmutableListOfImmutableItems[0].SetName("Jon") // SetName returns a new immutable Person instance
); // SetItem returns new immutable list instance

// notice both the item and the collection need to be reassigned. No other context will be polluted here
safeAsyncLocal.Value = someImmutableListOfImmutableItems;
```

EDIT: Some articles for people who want to read something perhaps more coherent than my ramblings here :)

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/
https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-3-runtime-context

And for some comparison, here's an article about how context is managed in JavaScript, which is single threaded but supports an asynchronous programming model (which I figure might help to illustrate how they relate/differ):

https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-execution-context-and-execution-stack-in-javascript-1c9ea8642dd0